# SQL Server ON DELETE SET NULL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In my database, I have an addresses table, and this table is used as the primary table in foreign keys with other tables (eg. customers, employees, etc...)

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b87e5) shows the relationship between `addresses` and `customers`, where `customers` has to 2 addresses.

Currently the FK's are set up as `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and I started changing them to `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

This has worked fine for most tables where there is only one address column. On one particular table where there is just one address column and on all tables where there are multiple address columns,I'm getting the error:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_customers_shipping_address' on table 'customers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

If I'm not using `CASCADE` why am I getting this error? And is there a way around it?

Comment: The error message is about `FK_customers_shipping_address`, however, that constraint is not in your SQLFiddle?

Comment: @NickyvV I updated the SQLFiddle. The second foreign key is commented out. If you uncomment it and build the schema, an error similar to the above will be displayed.

Comment: Vote for this feature on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/307723/allow-multiple-cascade-paths-for-foreign-key-and-on-dalete-update-cascade).

Answer (score 2):

`SET NULL` and `CASCADE` behave in the same way when it comes to this rule. You can't have "multiple cascade path". The message is a little unclear.

This is a SQL Server engine limitation. You can't do anything about it. Implement the cascading logic yourself.

Comment: Why does this error occur when I have just 1 address foreign key column in a table?

Comment: I don't think you understand what "multiple cascade path" means. This is about multiple path reaching the same "child table" in lack for a better word. SQL Server is, right now, incapable of processing a cascade or set null if multiple path can lead to the same row and modify it. (This is sad.)